# I only get the first id in jQuery from asp.net Razor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'am using asp.net mvc with Razor. This is my code

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="deleteSystemData" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-id="@item.SerialNumber">Delete reported data</button>
}

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var serialNumber;

        $('#deleteSystemData').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            serialNumber = $(this).data('id');
            console.log("This number: " + serialNumber);
            $("#deleteModal #serial-number").text(serialNumber);
        });

        $('#deleteConfirmed').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/MeterReading/DeleteSystemData',
                data: { serialNumber: serialNumber }
            }).done(function() {
                $('#deleteModal').modal('toggle');
                $("#delete-system-data-success").slideDown(500)
                  .delay(2500)
                  .slideUp(500);
            }).error(function () {
                $('#deleteModal').modal('toggle');
                $("#delete-system-data-error").slideDown(500)
                  .delay(2500)
                  .slideUp(500);
            }
            );
        });

    }
</script>
```

I get correct `data-id="@item.SerialNumber"` on all my buttons.
But my jQuery code only works with the first button. I have added a console.log (this number) in the first click event and I get a Id in the log when I click on the first button but the rest does not have any Id in the jQuery script.

My goal is to pass a id from a button to a asp.net controller and delete something with that id. I also have an bootstrap modal, but this works fine.

Comment: Your creating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html and will only ever select the first one. Use class names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should not have multiple elements with same Id** (`its ok to have it in plain HTML as it will not break any thing, but if you want to play with Jquery on these ids then its a Big NO!!!`) if you do then when you write Jquery to select the element with id then it will always return the first element with the given id in the DOM starting from the Top of the page.

`Solution:` **Add class to the buttons instead of id** and then write the scripts to play with this class..

So change the HTML inside your for loop as below

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs deleteSystemData" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-id="@item.SerialNumber">Delete reported data</button>
  }
```

**Note** `I have removed the id and added it to the class`

Next change your script section to below

```
$('.deleteSystemData').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  serialNumber = $(this).data('id');
  console.log("This number: " + serialNumber);
  $("#deleteModal #serial-number").text(serialNumber);
```

});

**Note** I have changed the selector `#deleteSystemData` to be `.deleteSystemData`

Answer (score 2):

You are creating duplicate Ids which is invalid. Try putting a class name instead.

```
@var i = 0;
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs deleteSystemData" id="deleteSystemData_@i" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-id="@item.SerialNumber">Delete reported data</button>
@i++;
}

window.onload = function () {
    var serialNumber;

    $('.deleteSystemData').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        serialNumber = $(this).attr('data-id'); // Gets the serial number
        console.log("This number: " + serialNumber);
        $("#deleteModal #serial-number").text(serialNumber);
    });
}
```

Comment: You have still left the invalid `id` attribute in there :)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. Updated the answer :)